# What does it mean when we say that this musical instrument is n octaves?

Tags: piano, keyboard, digital-piano, octave, instrument-range

When we say that this Piano/Keyboard is 5 octaves,Does it mean that 5 complete octaves (CDEFGAB CDEFGAB CDEFGAB CDEFGAB CDEFGAB) or 4 complete octaves plus C in octave 5 (CDEFGAB CDEFGAB CDEFGAB CDEFGAB C)?

Comment: I would not take it for granted, that the lowest tone is a C. Where the range ends, is typically indicated by the number of keys.

Answer (score 4):

It's 4 octaves + C: `CDEFGAB CDEFGAB CDEFGAB CDEFGAB CDEFGAB C`. You count 4 octaves from the starting note and add the starting note again: C1-C2 (first octave), C2-C3 (second), C3-C4(third), C4-C5(fourth), C5-C6(fifth), as above.

The first example you provided: `CDEFGAB CDEFGAB CDEFGAB CDEFGAB CDEFGAB` is 5 octaves minus a minor second. The second example: `CDEFGAB CDEFGAB CDEFGAB CDEFGAB C` is four octaves.

You can see an example on wikipedia's page on [piano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano#Keyboard):

> Almost every modern piano has 52 white keys and 36 black keys for a total of 88 keys (seven octaves plus a minor third, from A0 to C8). Many older pianos only have 85 keys (seven octaves from A0 to A7).

Υοu can also see how many A's there are here:

[image]